# How do I know when the FirebaseInstanceId is refreshed?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm using the following line of code to retrieve the FirebaseInstanceId:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().id
```

I'm using it as a unique app id and want to know when it changes, because I save it on the server side + I want store it in my shared preferences, so I need to know when it is refreshed.

1. Do I do this in FirebaseMessagingService's onNewToken(token: String), even though this method is meant for the FCM token? To my understanding, this the instance id is tightly coupled with the FCM token, and is in fact the prefix of it. Can there be a situation where the instance id is refreshed, but the FCM token remains the same (or vice versa)?
2. If so, what do I do in case my app doesn't need FCM, but I still want to store it? Implement it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) on FirebaseInstanceId states the following:

> Instance ID is stable except when:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - App is restored on a new device
> - User uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - User clears app data

So, the way I see it, you should be reasonably safe because that id can be either removed by your own code (via `Firebase#deleteInstanceId()`) or by the users when they restore/reinstall/uninstall their apps. There're no other cases where this id could be changed throughout the app's life.